# Explain "document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style;"

Tags: css

Can anyone explain the block of code:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style;
```

It will be good, if you use the below code as an example to explain:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(216, 54, 54);
}
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(50%,50%);
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    /* animation: fadeIn 2s ease-in; */
}
```

i just want to understand the code, I found it on net.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'analogy' - is the CSS you have given all within one stylesheet and is it the only (or at least the first) stylesheet?

Comment: Try making the code into a runnable snippet and putting some console.logs in there - for example at the final stage console.log(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style) will give you what properties have been set in the first (selector *) rule etc. It should help understand what is going on.

Comment: @AHaworth Hello sir, you suggested me a better way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `document` is your `document` object from which you can reach your stylesheets
- `document.styleSheets` is a read-only property that returns a [StyleSheetList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets
- `document.styleSheets[0]` extracts the first stylesheet from the stylesheetlist
- `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules` is a [CSSRuleList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/cssRules) read-only property, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/cssRules
- `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0]` is the first [CSSRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule) object in the CSSRuleList
- `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style` is the style of the given CSSRule object

You can explore this as per the snippet below:

```js
console.log(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style);
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(216, 54, 54);
}
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(50%,50%);
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    /* animation: fadeIn 2s ease-in; */
}
```